# n+1 problem laravel eloquent multiple relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with my eloquent relationship, I want to solve the n+1 problem using eager loading, but the queries still have an n+1 problem like the picture below

[image: N+1 problem in clockwork]

I use this code to create eager loading, but it's still not working, table relationship attached

```
$pengaduan = Pengaduan::with(['pengaduancomment','user'])->where('id', $id)->first();
```

[image: Relationship]

is my eager loading writing wrong? for the relation in the model file I'm sure it's correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
$pengaduan = Pengaduan::with(['pengaduancomment.user','user'])->where('id', $id)->first();
```